# MySQL: how to replicate users in master-master configuration

Tags: mysql, replication

I'm new to MySQL and have set up MySQL master-master replication according this tutorial:
https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-master-master-replication/

I have created some test users on the first DB and would like to know how can I replicated those users to the second master DB.

As far as I understood the administrative database, which is called 'mysql' must be replicated, so the users will be replicated.

Is it enough if I add the line below into my.cnf?

```
replicate-do-db mysql
```

Are there any other possibilities to replicated users?

The closest answer I found was [mysql-db-in-replication-but-users-created-on-master-are-not-replicating-on-slave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086049/mysql-db-in-replication-but-users-created-on-master-are-not-replicating-on-slave)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables and/or databases are replicated, not "users".  If you can isolate a "user" to a table or db, then you have a hope of achieving your stated goal.

But...  I will argue against doing *any* filtering between Masters in a Master-Master setup.  A major reason for having M-M is for "seamless" failover in the case of a crash on one of the Masters.  But that requires that *all* the data already exist on the other Master.

I hope Rackspace provides extra tools for M-M; otherwise it is so fraught with problems that I advise never using M-M.  (There are many discussions of such on this forum.)

Comment: Hi Rick, thank you for your quick answer. Would you rather prefer clustering then master-master replication?

Comment: @petob - Yes.  Galera (aka PXC) is what I recommend.  "InnoDB Cluster" should soon be a good contender.

Answer (score 1):

`replicate-do-db=mysql` will definitely work. I tried it on test servers.